# cant access to .vars.prototype from macros

Tags: twig, symfony

I'm trying to custom the add/delete feature of a collection with the `data-prototype` attr.
To do so, I use some twig `macro`:
view called by the controller

```
{# the principal view .html.twig #}    
{% from"AppBundle:Macros:tabRangeVal.html.twig" import tableau %}

[...]
    {{ tableau('InstrumentSharedUtils/File',form.documentations) }}
    {{ tableau('SpecificationsSheet/SpecificationSheet',form.list) }}
[...]
```

macro for `tableau`

```
{# /src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Macros/tabRangeVal.html.twig #}
{% macro tableau(classe, arrayVar) %}
    {% from "AppBundle:Form:"~ classe ~ ".html.twig" import val %}
    {% from "AppBundle:Form:"~ classe ~ ".html.twig" import label %}
    {% from "AppBundle:Macros:dataProto.html.twig" import proDataType %}
    <div class="well well-sm">
        <h5> {{ form_label(arrayVar) }}</h5>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><button class="btn btn-default btn-add-row" type="button" id="{{ "add_#{arrayVar.vars.id}" }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></th>
                    {{ label() }}
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="{{ "container_#{arrayVar.vars.id}" }}"   data-prototype="{{  proDataType(classe, arrayVar.vars.prototype)|e }}">
                {% for i in arrayVar %}
                    <tr >
                        <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-delete-row"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td>
                        {{ val(i) }}
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

macro for the data-prototype field

```
{# /src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Macros/dataProto.html.twig #}
{% macro proDataType(classe, value) %}
    {% from "AppBundle:Form:"~ classe ~ ".html.twig" import val %}
    <tr>
        {% for v in value %}
            <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-delete-row"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td>
            {{ val(v) }}
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endmacro %}
```

an exemple of the `AppBundle:Form:"~ classe ~ ".html.twig`

```
{# /src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Form/InstrumentSharedUtils/File.html.twig #}
{% macro val(var) %}
    <td>{{ form_widget(var.name, { 'attr': { 'class':'form-control' } }) }}</td>
    <td>{{ form_widget(var.path, { 'attr': { 'class':'form-control' } }) }}</td>
    <td>{{ form_widget(var.isExtra) }}</td>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro label() %}
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Path</th>
    <th>Is Extra</th>
{% endmacro %}
```

The problem is that I get the error

```
Method "name" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in AppBundle:Form:InstrumentSharedUtils/File.html.twig at line 2
```

The thing that really bothers me is that I can access to the name (and even the others `prototype.vars.children`) if I dont use macro

by exemple, the following code works:

```
{# principal view .html.twig #}

{% for i in form.documentations.vars.prototype %}
      {{ form_widget(i) }}
{% endfor %}
```

and i feel like its the exact same as above, with
`form.documentations` => `arrayVar`,
`arrayVar.vars.prototype` => `value`, and

```
{% for i in value %}
    {{ form_widget(i.name) }}
    {{ form_widget(i.path) }}
    {{ form_widget(i.isExtra) }}
{% endfor %}
```

the output should be the same ...

could you help me to find what is wrong in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I will probably flog myself to be so stupid, but by writing it down, I realised (in the last code section) that I made a mistake:

the `i in value` at the end is already either name or path or isExtra...
so when I try to access to `form.documentations.vars.prototype.name.name` its logic that I get a beautifull exception...

so the solution was to modify the dataproto macro

```
{% macro proDataType(classe, value) %} 
<tr class='block-to-remove'>
<td><button class='btn btn-default btn-delete-row'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span></button></td>
{% for truc in value %}
<td>{{ form_widget(truc, { 'attr': { 'class':'form-control' } }) }}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endmacro %}
```

and to send a `arrayVar.vars.prototype` to it